# Texture Painting stuttering

Tags: texture-painting, performance

i am having an issue where whilst I am painting (on a new layer, effecting Alpha) the stroke is very 'bumpy', and stutters. I have attached a video to demonstrate. I'm in Look Dev in the video, and are painting onto a 2048 x 2048 texture. Appreciate any help.

Video:
https://youtu.be/a9LPmrlIxVA

Comp:
AMD Ryzen 5 3600 cpu,
RTX 2060 Super,
16gb Ram,
SSD not HDD,

Comment: It may be due to lack of memory if your model is too complex or near a limit of vertices that allow the flow of calculations, you have tried a model with less polygons or less geometry ???

Comment: there is also the fact that he is calibrating his tool

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "calibrating his tool"? I have reverted back to 2.79, with the same model, and it seems to work better there...

Comment: Check your stroke steps as well as the stroke sample size -steps can be like 1 or 3, and sampling up can smooth the stroke except then it will lag a bit as you go higher. Also look at your brush Falloff curve, see if using a different profile will help there as well. The Shift-S lazy brush also causes some lag for calculation when using high sample rate.